# Create a curved row in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Is this possible to create/draw a row and make it curved?

I want to achieve this:
https://fvilarino.medium.com/creating-a-circular-list-in-jetpack-compose-29924c70e3e0

I adapt it to be horizontal instead of vertical, but the items are really huge. It's because of

```
val itemConstraints = Constraints.fixed(width = itemWidth, height = constraints.maxHeight)
```

I don't succeed to change it and find what to change to make it "smaller"
Do you have any idea how to do that?

Here is my current code:

```
{...}
Column {
    Text(
        text = "top",
    )

    CircularList(
        visibleItems = 9,
        circularFraction = .5f,
        modifier = Modifier.height(250.dp).background(Color.Cyan)
    ) {
        for (i in 0 until 40) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Red, CircleShape)
                    .requiredHeight(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                    .aspectRatio(1f),
                text = "$i",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            )
        }
    }

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f),
        text = "bottom",
    )
}
{...}

data class CircularListConfig(
    val contentWidth: Float = 0f,
    val numItems: Int = 0,
    val visibleItems: Int = 0,
    val circularFraction: Float = 1f,
    val overshootItems: Int = 0,
)

@Stable
interface CircularListState {
    val horizontalOffset: Float
    val firstVisibleItem: Int
    val lastVisibleItem: Int

    suspend fun snapTo(value: Float)
    suspend fun decayTo(velocity: Float, value: Float)
    suspend fun stop()
    fun offsetFor(index: Int): IntOffset
    fun setup(config: CircularListConfig)
}

class CircularListStateImpl(
    currentOffset: Float = 0f,
) : CircularListState {

    private val animatable = Animatable(currentOffset)
    private var itemWidth = 0f
    private var config = CircularListConfig()
    private var initialOffset = 0f
    private val decayAnimationSpec = FloatSpringSpec(
        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy,
        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow,
    )

    private val minOffset: Float
        get() = -(config.numItems - 1) * itemWidth

    override val horizontalOffset: Float
        get() = animatable.value

    override val firstVisibleItem: Int
        get() = ((-horizontalOffset - initialOffset) / itemWidth).toInt().coerceAtLeast(0)

    override val lastVisibleItem: Int
        get() = (((-horizontalOffset - initialOffset) / itemWidth).toInt() + config.visibleItems)
            .coerceAtMost(config.numItems - 1)

    override suspend fun snapTo(value: Float) {
        val minOvershoot = -(config.numItems - 1 + config.overshootItems) * itemWidth
        val maxOvershoot = config.overshootItems * itemWidth
        animatable.snapTo(value.coerceIn(minOvershoot, maxOvershoot))
    }

    override suspend fun decayTo(velocity: Float, value: Float) {
        val constrainedValue = value.coerceIn(minOffset, 0f).absoluteValue
        val remainder = (constrainedValue / itemWidth) - (constrainedValue / itemWidth).toInt()
        val extra = if (remainder <= 0.5f) 0 else 1
        val target =((constrainedValue / itemWidth).toInt() + extra) * itemWidth
        animatable.animateTo(
            targetValue = -target,
            initialVelocity = velocity,
            animationSpec = decayAnimationSpec,
        )
    }

    override suspend fun stop() {
        animatable.stop()
    }

    override fun setup(config: CircularListConfig) {
        this.config = config
        itemWidth = config.contentWidth / config.visibleItems
        initialOffset = (config.contentWidth - itemWidth) / 2f
    }

    override fun offsetFor(index: Int): IntOffset {
        val maxOffset = config.contentWidth / 2f + itemWidth / 2f
        val y = (horizontalOffset + initialOffset + index * itemWidth)
        val deltaFromCenter = (y - initialOffset)
        val radius = config.contentWidth / 2f
        val scaledY = deltaFromCenter.absoluteValue * (config.contentWidth / 2f / maxOffset)
        val x = if (scaledY < radius) {
            sqrt((radius * radius + scaledY * scaledY))
        } else {
            0f
        }
        return IntOffset(
            x = y.roundToInt(),
            y = (x * config.circularFraction).roundToInt(),
        )
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as CircularListStateImpl

        if (animatable.value != other.animatable.value) return false
        if (itemWidth != other.itemWidth) return false
        if (config != other.config) return false
        if (initialOffset != other.initialOffset) return false
        if (decayAnimationSpec != other.decayAnimationSpec) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = animatable.value.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + itemWidth.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + config.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + initialOffset.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + decayAnimationSpec.hashCode()
        return result
    }

    companion object {
        val Saver = Saver<CircularListStateImpl, List<Any>>(
            save = { listOf(it.horizontalOffset) },
            restore = {
                CircularListStateImpl(it[0] as Float)
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberCircularListState(): CircularListState {
    val state = rememberSaveable(saver = CircularListStateImpl.Saver) {
        CircularListStateImpl()
    }
    return state
}

@Composable
fun CircularList(
    visibleItems: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: CircularListState = rememberCircularListState(),
    circularFraction: Float = 1f,
    overshootItems: Int = 3,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    check(visibleItems > 0) { "Visible items must be positive" }
    check(circularFraction > 0f) { "Circular fraction must be positive" }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier
            .drag(state),
        content = content,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val itemWidth = constraints.maxWidth / visibleItems
        val itemConstraints = Constraints.fixed(width = itemWidth, height = constraints.maxHeight)
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable -> measurable.measure(itemConstraints) }
        state.setup(
            CircularListConfig(
                contentWidth = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat(),
                numItems = placeables.size,
                visibleItems = visibleItems,
                circularFraction = circularFraction,
                overshootItems = overshootItems,
            )
        )
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = constraints.maxHeight,
        ) {
            for (i in state.firstVisibleItem..state.lastVisibleItem) {
                placeables[i].placeRelative(state.offsetFor(i))
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ReturnFromAwaitPointerEventScope", "MultipleAwaitPointerEventScopes")
private fun Modifier.drag(
    state: CircularListState,
) = pointerInput(Unit) {
    val decay = splineBasedDecay<Float>(this)
    coroutineScope {
        while (true) {
            val pointerId = awaitPointerEventScope { awaitFirstDown().id }
            state.stop()
            val tracker = VelocityTracker()
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                horizontalDrag(pointerId) { change ->
                    val verticalDragOffset = state.horizontalOffset + change.positionChange().x
                    launch {
                        state.snapTo(verticalDragOffset)
                    }
                    tracker.addPosition(change.uptimeMillis, change.position)
                    change.consumePositionChange()
                }
            }
            val velocity = tracker.calculateVelocity().x
            val targetValue = decay.calculateTargetValue(state.horizontalOffset, velocity)
            launch {
                state.decayTo(velocity, targetValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output,

[image]

The purpose is to have the "cyan" background matching the minimal height (currently 200.dp otherwise I don't see it), items shouldn't go under the layout and the first item should be on the left.